# My CSS code is not being applied even with the correct class

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

My code is adding the active class in the active link but the style css for the active class is not showing on the browser. It does find it, however is not applying it. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
            <Menu iconShape="square">
              <MenuItem icon={<FiHome />}>
                Home
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<FaList />}> Cadastrar Problemática <NavLink to='/problematica'/>  </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<FaRegHeart />}> Cadastrar Usuário <NavLink to='/colaborador' /> </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<RiPencilLine />}>Reuniões Marcadas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem icon={<BiCog />}>Configuração</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </SidebarContent>



.active {
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fb8500;  
    font-size: 50rem;
    line-height: 10rem;
  }
```

Comment: is that how you insert your css? lets presume its not, if your class is correct and your css is included correctly, I can only assume something is overwritting your rules, use the inspector in your browser where you can select the element in question and check the css ruleset to se what is applied or not

Comment: What version of `reacty-router-dom` are you using as well. Version 6 recently released and changed the `NavLink` API a bit.

Comment: @Breezer I've already checked if it had any other class overwriting, and tried specifing the css selector, none of those worked

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah, I'm using the version6. I read the documentation but nothing helped me

Comment: Yes, I see it still applies an `active` class by default. Double check that your CSS is being applied to the document and that nothing is overriding the CSS for the link.